# simple_form with Bootstrap check box

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, erb, simple-form

I'm using simple_form with Bootstrap and I would like to have my "Remember me" check box be inline to the left of the label, as in the Twitter Bootstrap docs: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

My form code looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => 'well'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable?  %>

    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign In" %>

<% end %>
```

The result is the the "Remember me" label on top of a check box.

What have I messed up?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There's a number of options for this, see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/424) for more of them:

The most straightforward (I think) is to use `:label => false` and `:inline_label => true`, on your checkbox, to change the where in the HTML the label is placed.

`<%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => true if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>`

This produces something like this for me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I just spent two hours trying to figure it out :)

Answer (score 6):

@alol's answer works great for a vertical form (labels on top of the fields), but if you're doing a horizontal form and you want the check box labels to show to the right of the checkbox, but still keep with the layout of the form, you can do this:

```
f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean, :label => "&nbsp;", :inline_label => true if devise_mapping.rememberable?
```

You can also pass a specific label to use as the inline label instead of `true`, if you need to:

```
f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean, :label => "&nbsp;", :inline_label => "My Label" if devise_mapping.rememberable?
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this one is a bit simpler:

```
f.input :remember_me, wrapper: :vertical_boolean, as: :boolean  if devise_mapping.rememberable?
```

The wrapper comes bundled in `config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb` at least from `simple_form 3.1.0rc2` when installed with:

```
rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap
```