# Simple Form check box left alignment

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a rails 4 app with simple form.

There is a check box element in the app where the box is to the left of the label.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
    <%= f.label  :'How will you share the project results?', :class => 'question-project' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class= "response-project">
      <%= f.input :report,  as: :boolean, inline_label: 'A report on project outcomes', label: false, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline' %>
      <%= f.input :other_outcome, :as => :boolean, :label => false, :inline_label => true %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The css for response-project is:

```
.response-project {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: light-grey;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 2;

}
```

The check box is aligned further to the left than all of the remaining form elements. That seems to come from simple form. Does anyone know how to turn that alignment off so that the check box is aligned to the left of the form, in a uniform line with all other elements of the form?

Thank you

Comment: might wrote this code before starting tag of form?

Comment: Hi Ali, I didn't quite understand what you mean. Is there a tag to use to indent the check box?

Comment: I mean that make sure input is inside <form> and </form>. would you plz paste more codes of your page. it may helps.

Comment: also add **:style => "float:left;** to both input and lable

Comment: Hi Ali - float:left won't work because it will push the code to the left of the container. I want the line aligned left in line with all the other elements in the form. At the moment, the elements are to the left, but the check box sits further left than the remaining form elements.

Comment: can you replicate your problem on a Fiddle or maybe a live web? we can inspect it that way and maybe it may have an easy solution with a few css properties

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I'm not sure how to make it run when i don't use any js in fiddle, but i have copied the relevant extract into this page: https://jsfiddle.net/bnkoc6s7/

Comment: Hi - i added more of the form. This is driving me crazy. Thanks for trying to help. My objective is to have the far left side of the check box align with the left side of the label above it. At the moment, the check box is to the left of the outer left edge of the label above it and the labels on the check boxes themselves align with the label above (with the checkboxes sticking out to the left of everything else).

Answer (score 0):

There was a Stack post very similar like this here: [simple_form with Bootstrap check box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656819/simple-form-with-bootstrap-check-box)

What you need to do is create a custom wrapper in config/initializers/simple_form.rb. Read more here https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers

Comment: Hi Zippo9. Thanks - I know how to get the box inline with the label, but my specific issue is that the box is aligned to the left of the outer left side of the rest of the form elements, so that if this form element is on of several elements in a form, the check box is aligned further left than all other form elements. I'm trying to work out how to use the check box inline alignment so that the check box is vertically aligned with all other form elements.

Comment: Oh well then I would recommend a <%= f.collection_check_boxes %> see here http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/ActionViewExtensions/Builder#collection_check_boxes-instance_method

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'm not explaining my problem clearly. No - I don't need a collection. I have a single check box on this form element (one checkbox with one label). I want that line to be left aligned in vertical alignment with all other form elements. When the checkbox is inline with the label in this element, the box is too far to the left (outside the parameters of all other elements in the form.

Answer (score 0):

According to bootstrap, you need to layout the checkbox style and class to be something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kevin - yes I'm aware that's how bootstrap does it. I can't figure out how to make that work with simple form (see my boolean checkbox function above). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

add `:item_wrapper_class => 'inline'` to your code.

Comment: Hi Ali - I'm afraid that doesn't help. The check box is inline with the label, but the checkbox is aligned to the left of the left side of the container in which all form elements are set.

Comment: Are you sure it is inside <form></form> tags?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to align the left side of the check box inside the left side of the form container. All elements of the form are inside tags. There must be something in simple form that puts inline checkboxes to the right of the left side of the form edge.